# A row associates with session is deleted when user logout in YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a site that uses YII. One thing that it does is storing session information into a MySql database table YiiSession. Also in a separate table (users_sessions), a new row is inserted with the following information:

- session id
- user id
- online status of a user

I create another table for session because YiiSession is part of YII. Also users_session keeps track online status of a user, whereas YiiSession doesn't.

I only make an insertion into users_session during user login.

But I don't understand that when user logs out, the session that associates with the user got deleted.

Note that the session_id in the users_session is a foreign key to the one in YiiSession. But the one in YiiSession still exists even though it has an expiration date.

What mechanism that possibly deletes the row? Please help.

Comment: I think you could phrase your question better. "But I don't understand that when user logs out, the session that associates with the user got deleted." Usually session-deletion(destroy) are contained in log-outs so that makes perfect sense, I guess you're talking from the SQL perspective but to be sure you need to rephrase that.

Comment: Hi Jonast92, I don't understand how come it got deleted in user_session (the table is created by me) but not in YiiSession (the table is part of Yii setting). And which mechanism that deletes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend `CDbHttpSession` and overwrite the method `destroySession($id)`. There you append the code and delete your entry also.

Configure Yii to use your session class instead of it's own in config/main.php:

```
'session' => array(
    'autoStart' => true,
    'class' => 'application.components.<your session class name>',
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'sessionTableName' => 'session',
    'autoCreateSessionTable' => false,
    'timeout' => 3600, // 60 min
),
```

However I would not do this with a separate table, just add some fields to the YiiSession table. That's what I did and it works pretty well.

**EDIT:**
You should create a file named `MyDbHttpSession.php` in `protected/components`.
In this file extend CDbHttpSession like so:

```
class MyDbHttpSession extends CDbHttpSession
{
    protected function createSessionTable($db, $tableName)
    {
        // basically this is a copy of CDbHttpSession

        $db->createCommand()->createTable($tableName, array(
            'id' => 'CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY',
            'expire' => 'integer',
            'data' => $blob,
            // your additional fields
            'idUser' => 'INT(10) NULL',
            'online' => 'TINYINT(1)',
            // more of your fields here if you have
        ));
    }

    // this sets the user ID by session ID
    public function setIdUser($idUser)
    {
        $db = $this->getDbConnection();
        $db->setActive(true);
        $db->createCommand()->update($this->sessionTableName, array('idUser' => (int) $idUser),
            'id=:id', array(':id' => $this->sessionId)
        );
    }

    // and this sets the online status, pass true or false to $online
    public function setOnline($online)
    {
        $db = $this->getDbConnection();
        $db->setActive(true);
        $db->createCommand()->update($this->sessionTableName, array('online' => (int) $online),
            'id=:id', array(':id' => $this->sessionId)
        );
    }
}
```

Set Yii to use your session class instead of it's own like I wrote above.

You should already have a class `WebUser`. If not, create one in `protected/components` and extend `CWebUser`.
In this class add a method `afterLogin`:

```
public function afterLogin($fromCookie)
{
    // store user ID and online status in session table
    Yii::app()->session->setIdUser($this->id);
    Yii::app()->session->setOnline(true);

    return parent::afterLogin($fromCookie);
}
```

You can from wherever you are in Yii use `Yii::app()->session->setOnline(true);` or `Yii::app()->session->setOnline(false);`

Comment: chris, thanks for your suggestion, but I still haven't got the answer on what mechanism that deletes the row in users_session but not in YiiSession.

Comment: If I want to use 1 table YiiSession instead of two tables, how can I make so that every time a user logs in, the session also insert additional information like user ip address, user id, and user status? Could you give me a pointer so that I can understand the mechanism? regards

Comment: Ok I have added an example.